# How to extract specific data from python dictionary for images

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to do Gender classification, I have downloaded database having around 60k images in 100 directories, plus I have download .mat file that contains name, gender labels, age, etc.

I have loaded a .mat file using scipy command and there I can dictionary having data related to all images. Now, I want to feed data to CNN, but before this, I need to extract labels of images from that dictionary.

Can anyone tell me how can I specifically extract labels for gender (0:for female, 1: male, nan: for unknown) from this dictionary?

Thanks very much